# What is this code actually doing

Tags: c++

every one seems to be in agreement that this is the proper way to convert command line char array to a string.

```
    vector<std::string> params(argv+1, argv+argc);
```

but i'm not really understanding what is going on here because when i try to print argv[1] it is just the first letter of the string. what is actually going on here. is it some kind of pointer math that leads you to the rest of the data i'm just sure how adding 2(the value of argc) to argv is able to get all of the chars in that array for just that one argument.

for example printing argv[1] like so

```
cout << *argv[1];
```

gives back t which is the first letter of the second parameter which is test.txt.

thanks to Fred for point this out

```
cout << argv[1];
```

does return the whole string but no way of me testing can i do this

```
cout << argv + argc;
```

and make that move between arguments.

Comment: MCVE is the king. How are you printing your `argv[1]`?

Comment: No, `argv[1]` is not just the first letter...

Comment: Try `cout << argv[1] << '\n';` instead. `*argv[1]` is indeed a single character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the code is populating the vector with tokens from the command line.

The code is using [the std::vector constructor for sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) and passing in an *iterator* to the first argument (after the program name) and one past the last argument on the command line.

To verify, try this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
{
  std::cout << "Argument [" << i << "]: " << argv[i] << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "\nFrom vector:\n"
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < params.size(); ++j)
{
  std::cout << "params[" << j << "]: " << params[j] << "\n";
}
```